# Переключение на процесс (pid python)

Tags: python, бот, процесс, psutil

Имею некий pid процесса (запущенное приложение).
Мне необходимо посредством python переключиться в него (если свернуто, развернуть. Если на заднем фоне - передвинуть вперед)
Честно говоря, искал что-то вроде focus(pid) в psutil, но не нашел.

Отрывок кода

```
import psutil

#   проверка запущенного процесса
process_name = "myprocess.exe"
pid = None

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if process_name in proc.name():
       pid = proc.pid
       break

if pid == False:
    print('End run')
else:
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    p.nice(256)
    print(p)
```

Comment: нужно вызвать методы ОС , менеджера окон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб не вникать в win32gui.EnumWindows можно воспользоваться библиотекой pywinauto

```
from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().connect(process=pid)
app.top_window().set_focus()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь переключается)